# Is there any kind of notification mechanism to let me know when my comments are deleted?

Tags: support, comments, moderation, notifications

I've left a comment to this question:
[How to deal with players rejecting the question premise](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89039/how-to-deal-with-players-rejecting-the-question-premise)

The question had zero comments at the moment. Now it has zero comments as well.

Was my comment deleted? Were all comments deleted? By whom and why? How can I know if my comment was inappropriate, in order to prevent making bad comments in the future?

Is there any kind of notification mechanism to let me know when my comments are deleted?

Comment: Does [Why are site comments being deleted?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1174/why-are-site-comments-being-deleted) answer your question? If so we can mark this as a duplicate. If not, we can focus on the part that it doesn't cover.

Comment: Do you remember the words of your comment?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie it answers, why comments can be deleted. It doesn't answer, if the comment author gets any notification

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith, yes, it was "Have you stopped beating your wife?", in quotes.

Comment: @enkryptor yeah its not something that is helping to improve the question in anyway and while it was probably meant as a joke or example regarding the question system of Dread and uncomforatable questions the lack of context made it problematic. Someone may even have flagged it as any of the reasons in shown in the Meta question linked by SevenSidedDie

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith I didn't ask, why my comment was deleted. I asked, if I can have any kind of notification, when my comments are being deleted.

Comment: @enkryptor you do indeed appear to be asking why your comment was deleted, since your question says: "Was my comment deleted? ... By whom and why?" The only part that seems to talk about a notification is maybe the second half of the title.

Comment: There is no notification built into the system.

Comment: @doppelgreener are you trying to explain me, what my true question was? I want to know, are there any notifications about deleted comments. My words might not be so clear, but I know what I mean. You can suggest how can I improve the question though.

Comment: @enkryptor Nothing of the sort. You seemed to be suggesting your question (as written) had asked whether there was a notification mechanism avialable, I was pointing out it did not in fact appear to ask that. I have improved it by adding a question about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I flagged your comment as too chatty, and [a moderator](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) followed up by deleting it. From my memory and yours, your comment was (quotes included):

> "Have you stopped beating your wife?"

The wife-beating bit isn't important; you were chiming in with something character-building related. It could've been "Have you stopped taking your vitamins?" or something else dealing with a relatively harmless topic.

Ultimately comments on main site are primarily for one of two things:

- requesting clarification
- suggesting an improvement

This was neither. At its simplest you were just chiming in with some kind of question-prompt idea, one could also surmise you might have been trying to hint at a point (maybe "there's some questions people would of course rather reject"?) but you never said that point, and comments aren't the place for making a point — answers are, so long as you're also answering the question.

It was a chatty comment that didn't add much and didn't do what comments are supposed to do, and had no reason to not be deleted, so I flagged it, and it got deleted.

There is no notification mechanism for your comments getting deleted. Comment deletion doesn't matter enough to get notifications about it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, why my comment was deleted. However, what I asked is slightly different. I asked, were there any kind of notifications. How can I know, if my comment was deleted?

Comment: Also comments are systematically viewed as the least important, most temporary, and  superfluous aspect of the site.  They are there as an asynchronous way to improve Questions and Answers without simply down voting or closing/making edits.

Answer (score 10):

#### The simple answer to the question is "No."

There isn't a feature to indicate comments being deleted.  I doubt SE/SO will want to spend the time and effort on that tool since comments are not what is important: the questions and answers are.

#### But My Comments Are Precious

(Full disclaimer: I have as much pride in authorship as anyone, and during my early interactions on this SE I put too much value on comments.  I had to adapt).

1. Each of us makes comments for a variety of reasons.  I have found by
   experience that the following attitude is the one to take: *expect
   comments to be deleted, and be surprised when they are not*.
2. An associated good attitude to take: once someone acts on a comment of yours either delete it yourself, move to chat, or expect
   it to eventually go away.  **The whole aim of comments is to improve
   questions and answers**.
3. A "model citizen" way to approach comments, along with the two
   above: if you find comments that are too chatty or not constructive,
   flag them for clean up.  Your mods now and again perform janitorial
   services. (Term of phrase shamelessly stolen from SSD).

Comment: When you say "responds to a comment" in guideline 2, I think you might mean "acts on a comment". Responding could be interpreted to include someone just saying "@korvin good idea" under which circumstance one doesn't yet need to delete their comment.

Comment: @doppelgreener Done and well spotted!

Comment: +1.  If you are worried about your comments being deleted, you're using comments inappropriately.